# Can Visual Studio Code be configured to "Save as..." starting in the same folder where the currently open file already exists on a UNC path?

Tags: visual-studio-code, unc, save-as

***Observation / Issue***

- Expected and desired: With a file open from a folder on a drive letter C: D: etc whether mapped or local, the "Save As..." function will open the save dialog *in the same folder where the existing open file is already located.*
- Unexpected and undesired: With a file open from UNC path, such as `\\fileserver\dir\should-open-here\readme.txt` using "Save As..." opens the save dialog to `C:\Users\<user>\Documents` instead of where the file is.

***Question:***

- Is there a configuration for VSCode that allows the "start from where I already am" behavior for a folder located within a UNC path?

***Other Notes***

- In my searching the closest related thing I've found is a closed from over 3 years ago:
  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98198
- Although I can map to a drive letter, and it works correctly to start where I already am, that throws off other things and in general I believe shouldn't be necessary. Drive letters aren't scalable, and variable in that they don't have canonical meaning to a certain location, whereas UNC path is unique and certain (within the LAN context where this matters).
- One of the things that fails to work with drive letters is "open file location" from a search in Windows Explorer. Doing that opens the UNC path even if the drive letter path is searched.
- The "workaround" of having the same folders open in windows explorer, one by drive letter, another by UNC, is tedious and fatiguing.

Thanks for any and all insight. I'm not even sure if this is a "thing" or if mine is a unique case.

// Nate